# What does とくと mean?

Tags: words, archaic-language

At one point in a particular work of fiction, a character announces 我が力、とくとご覧あれ！ As I understand, it means 'Behold my power!' But I don't know what とくと means. I would guess it's archaic, since the whole sentence sounds archaic, but I might be wrong. Is it some kind of honorific word?

Comment: Off-topic: Why on Earth has my question got this many views?

Comment: I think it must have appeared on [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions), but I don't see it there right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「とくと」 means 「よく」= "carefully", "thoroughly", etc.  It should be found in any small monolingual dictionaries.

The word is not really archaic; It is just not used often in informal conversation.

It is used quite often in dramatic- or theatrical-sounding ***imperative or request*** asking one to do something thoroughly just like in your example. 
In other words, one would expect to hear it more often in fiction than in real life.

The verbs most often used with 「とくと」 would be 「見{み}る」,「聞{き}く」,「考{かんが}える」, etc.  「ご覧{らん}になる」 in your example, of course, is the honorific form of 「見る」.

Answer (score 0):

とくと　is used when you're trying to check on something thoroughly.
It is another form of totteyoku とってよく.

Take something in one's hand to have a good look.
何かを手にとってよく見る

Comment: 「とくと」=「[篤]{とく}と」. Are you saying とくと is short for とってよく(取って良く)?